# How to properly use curve's value to animate a widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  double _dx1 = 0;
  double _dx2 = 0;
  final Duration _duration = Duration(seconds: 1);
  final Curve _curve = Curves.linear;

  void _play() {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    _dx1 = width;
    var i = 0;
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 1), (timer) {
      if (i > 1000) {
        timer.cancel();
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _dx2 = _curve.transform(i / 1000) * width;
          i++;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _play,
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            AnimatedPositioned(
              left: _dx1,
              duration: _duration,
              curve: _curve,
              child: _box,
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: _dx2,
              top: 60,
              child: _box,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container get _box => Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.red);
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

As you can see my second custom animated box doesn't catch up with the first default `AnimatedPositioned` widget.

**Note**: This can easily be done using `Tween` and `AnimationController` but I just want to know why I'm unable to correctly use `Curve`'s value  to match the default behavior.

Comment: @pskink Ok, but doesn't the `Timer` block run for just 1s?

Comment: add `print('${DateTime.now()} ${timer.tick}');` inside `(timer) { ..`. callback and you will see how it works

Comment: @pskink Oops, you're right I was doing it wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumption**: The callback is periodically called for every millisecond.
**Expected Result**: After 1 second, i = 1000;

The assumption is wrong. Add the below code to verify:

```dart
void _play() {
  ...
  var i = 0;
  final start = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 1), (timer) {
    final elapse = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - start;
    print('elapse = $elapse');
    print('i = $i');
    print('ticks = ${timer.tick}');
    print('######################');
    ...
  });
}
```

On my pc the last value is:

```
elapse = 14670
i = 1001
ticks = 14670
######################
```

So this implies that it took 14 seconds on my PC for 1001 callbacks. That's not what we were expecting. What we can infer from this is that some callbacks are missed and `i` does not reflect the time elapsed.

However, the value we need is `timer.tick`. Quoting the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/tick.html)

> If a periodic timer with a non-zero duration is delayed too much, so more than one tick should have happened, all but the last tick in the past are considered "missed", and no callback is invoked for them. The tick count reflects the number of durations that have passed and not the number of callback invocations that have happened.

So, `tick` tells us the number of `period`s that have passed. The below code will catch up with the `AnimatedPositioned`

```
void _play() {
  final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  _dx1 = width;

  final period = Duration(milliseconds: 1);
  Timer.periodic(period, (timer) {
    final elapsed = timer.tick * period.inMilliseconds;
    if (elapsed > _duration.inMilliseconds) {
      timer.cancel();
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _dx2 = _curve.transform(elapsed / _duration.inMilliseconds) * width;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Now, you might see some stutter where our box might be a bit ahead or behind the `AnimatedPositioned`, this is because we use `Timer` but the `AnimatedPositioned` uses `Ticker`. The difference is `Timer.periodic` is driven by the `Duration` we passed as period, but `Ticker` is driven by `SchedulerBinding.scheduleFrameCallback`. So, the instant the value `_dx2` is updated and the instant the frame is rendered on the screen might not be the same. Add the fact that some callbacks are missed!

Comment: I only read the first line and left rest of your code haha. My assumptions were actually wrong. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: However, I didn't really get why 2nd box is ahead of first. Are you saying  that when we use `AnimatedPositioned` and change any of its property (inside `setState`), it won't start the animation instantly but might take a few ms?

Comment: Say the callback was called for every 1ms. But since most screens are 60fps, only 60 of those 1000 values of `_dx2` will be shown on screen. But what if the number of times `_dx2` is updated is less than 60 per second. On my PC the value was updated only 28 times. So, in those 60 frames, the value of `_dx2` is not uniform and some values are used for more than 2 frames. However, if we made use of `Ticker` instead of `Timer`, which uses frame callbacks instead of duration, you will get the same effect as that of `AnimatedPositioned`. Our box will be ahead if our value is more up-to-date.